# Simple export/import in React returning undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have a local package I'm installing in my React app via:

```
"my-library": "file:~/Desktop/my-library"
```

Its `main` file is simply this:

```
export class MyClass {

}
```

which when transpiled with babel looks like this:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var MyClass = exports.MyClass = function MyClass() {
  _classCallCheck(this, MyClass);
};

},{}]},{},[1]);
```

Now, I should be able to import this into my app with just this right?

```
import {MyClass} from "my-library";
```

**However, `MyClass` is `undefined` after import.**

I know my-library as a package is loaded correctly, because if I cause an exception in the main file, my React app will pick it up and the import will fail.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is actually not exporting anything because there is only a name of class defined but not **the name** of the export.

```
export class MyClass {
```

that's it's bundling something like this:

```
var MyClass = exports.MyClass = function MyClass() {
```

instead:

```
var MyClass = function MyClass() {
```

So I think you need to name your named export:

```
export const MyClass = class MyClass {}
```

Comment: I don't think this worked. Or, it didn't change the compiled file at all. The compiled file already has this: `var MyClass = exports.MyClass = function MyClass() ` which means it is naming the export, no?

Comment: @Snowman it should work. See example on codesanbox https://codesandbox.io/s/yjoqovz4jz

Comment: `export class MyClass` and `export const MyClass = class MyClass` yield the same exact transpilation with babel. So no difference there. The issue must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
let units={var1:var_,var2:var2}

units.MyClass =MyClass ;
module.exports = units;
```

or this one

```
class MyClass {
.
.
.
}
export default MyClass
```

Comment: units is a array (name it as you like ), if you want to export more than one item you can specify

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that I was `browserify` in my grunt task (since this library is also made to run in the web). This changed my file in a way that broke importing for native. Disabling browserify fixed the issue. Now I need to find a real solution for making it work on both.

Update: the solution to making browserify work on both web and native is to use `standalone` mode.

```
  browserifyOptions: {
    standalone: 'MyModule'
  }
```